# Vim not displaying character values correctly

Tags: vimrc

I opened up vim and noticed that nothing is displaying properly. mI have no idea of the cause as last time I was in vim there was nothing of the sort. I have tried setting the encoding

[image]

Comment: We will need more details about your OS, your terminal emulator, how it renders the characters for other programs, a minimal vimrc which reproduces your problems... Some basic information to help people to help you.

Comment: looks like a terminal problem.

Comment: Agreed with @ChristianBrabandt —check the value of `$TERM`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal content - you can copy/paste the text.